# My activity get blinked when I open it using TimerTask in Android

Tags: java, android

Here is the code that opens home activity auto from MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Timer t = new Timer();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TimerTask task= new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            }
        };

        t.schedule(task,4000);
    }
```

Comment: try this Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class);
   intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

Answer (score 0):

you can use this line of code instead of timer task:

```
         new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION));
            finish();;
        }
    }, 4000);
```